# interval not getting cleared by clearInterval()

Tags: javascript

I've been playing around with canvas and I'm trying to make a square that moves and jumps, the moving part is done, but the jumping part has an issue: it jumps faster every time you jump

[here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a6duzpzu/)

and here's the code:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                                 VARIABLES                                 //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var canvas = document.getElementById("arena");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var square = new Player("#330099", 32, 32);

var keys = [];
var velX = 0;
var speed = 50;
var friction = 0.8;
var jumping = false;
var jumpInterval;



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                                  OBJECTS                                  //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function Player(color, width, height, jumpHeight, drawAction){
    this.color = color || "#000000";
    this.width = width || 50;
    this.height = height || 50;
    this.jumpHeight = jumpHeight || 100;
    this.x = canvas.width/2;
    this.y = canvas.height-this.height;
    this.draw = drawAction || function(){
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    };
};



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                              EVENT LISTENERS                              //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});
document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = false;
});



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                                 FUNCTIONS                                 //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function Jump(){
    if(jumping == true){
        if(square.y+square.height > canvas.height-square.jumpHeight){
            square.y--;
            console.log("jumping");
        } else { jumping = false; console.log("peak reached"); }
    }

    if(jumping == false){
        if(square.y < canvas.height-square.height){ square.y++; console.log("falling"); }
        else { clearInterval(jumpInterval); console.log("interval cleaned"); }
    }
}



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                               UPDATE & DRAW                               //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function update(){
    window.requestAnimationFrame(update);

    if(keys[37]){ //left arrow
        if(velX > -speed){
            velX--;
        }
    }
    if(keys[39]){ //right arrow
        if(velX < speed){
            velX++;
        }
    }

    if(keys[32]){ //space bar
        if(jumping == false){
            jumping = true;
        }

        jumpInterval = setInterval(Jump, 10);
    }

    /*
    if(keys[39] == false){
        jumping = false;
        jumpInterval = setInterval(Jump, 10);
    }
    */

    if(velX != 0){
        velX *= friction;
    }

    square.x += velX;

    draw()
}

function draw(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    square.draw();
}

update()
```

the console constantly prints out "interval cleaned" so it looks like it's not actually clearing it.

which means that there's more and more intervals every time I jump, which would explain that issue, except that I have no idea why it's not getting cleared!

(it also seems to go faster when I move to the right and jump)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, while the spacebar is pressed, you set a new interval at each `update` call:

```js
if(keys[32]){ //space bar
    if(jumping == false){
        jumping = true;
    }
    jumpInterval = setInterval(Jump, 10);
}
```

But most probably, `update` will be called multiple times while the spacebar is pressed. In that case you will only clear the last interval.

Instead, you should only set one interval:

```js
if(keys[32]){ //space bar
    if(jumping == false){
        jumping = true;
        jumpInterval = setInterval(Jump, 10);
    }
}
```

```js
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                                 VARIABLES                                 //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var canvas = document.getElementById("arena");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var square = new Player("#330099", 32, 32);

var keys = [];
var velX = 0;
var speed = 50;
var friction = 0.8;
var jumping = false;
var jumpInterval;



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                                  OBJECTS                                  //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function Player(color, width, height, jumpHeight, drawAction) {
  this.color = color || "#000000";
  this.width = width || 50;
  this.height = height || 50;
  this.jumpHeight = jumpHeight || 100;
  this.x = canvas.width / 2;
  this.y = canvas.height - this.height;
  this.draw = drawAction || function() {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
  };
};



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                              EVENT LISTENERS                              //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});
document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  keys[e.keyCode] = false;
});



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                                 FUNCTIONS                                 //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function Jump() {
  if (jumping == true) {
    if (square.y + square.height > canvas.height - square.jumpHeight) {
      square.y--;
      console.log("jumping");
    } else {
      jumping = false;
      console.log("peak reached");
    }
  }

  if (jumping == false) {
    if (square.y < canvas.height - square.height) {
      square.y++;
      console.log("falling");
    } else {
      clearInterval(jumpInterval);
      console.log("interval cleaned");
    }
  }
}



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                               UPDATE & DRAW                               //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function update() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
  if (keys[37]) { //left arrow
    if (velX > -speed) {
      velX--;
    }
  }
  if (keys[39]) { //right arrow
    if (velX < speed) {
      velX++;
    }
  }
  if (keys[32]) { //space bar
    if (jumping == false) {
      jumping = true;
      jumpInterval = setInterval(Jump, 10);
    }
  }
  if (velX != 0) {
    velX *= friction;
  }
  square.x += velX;
  draw()
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  square.draw();
}
update()
```

```css
#arena {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="arena" width="400px" height="200px;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Confirmed: if you press the space bar only absolutely quickly in OP’s code it’ll work as expected.

Comment: yup, this works, but how could I make it so that it doesn't go insane when holding it down or tapping really quickly? but adding a `if(jumping==true){--something--}`?

Comment: nevermind, I've found a way, I've added a `blockSpacebar = true;` at the beginning of the function and `blockSpacebar = false;` after clearing the interval